# Symfony2 assetic:dump wrong write_to path

Tags: symfony, assets, assetic

I have a longtime problem with assetic:dump. I wanna use "assetic" to get Javascript and CSS files from different bundles (I wrote) and collect them to dev and prod environment in the templates. Everytime I wanna dump new files, the assetic:dump command try to write in a complete broken path.

```
app/console assetic:dump

  [RuntimeException]                                                                                       
  Unable to create directory /var/www/app/../web//var/www/app/../htdocs/css
```

I also try writing in: (nothing works)

```
app/console assetic:dump web
app/console assetic:dump .
app/console assetic:dump /var/www/web
```

I configured assetic like this:

```
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    read_from: "%kernel.root_dir%/../web"
    write_to: "%kernel.root_dir%/../web"
    bundles:
      - MyCodeBundle
      - NextCodeBundle
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        lessphp:
            file: %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/oyejorge/less.php/lessc.inc.php
            apply_to: "\.less$"
        cssrewrite: ~
```

I use also *BraincraftedBootstrapBundle* to use Twitter Bootstrap Js/CSS in my templates.

Where I can fix the path of assetic:dump?

Comment: Do you have symlinks within your SF installation?

Comment: yes, web is a symlink to another directory. is that a problem? in a special environment, it's necessary, that "web" is named "htdocs", so i created a "htdocs" directory and web is a symlink to this.

Comment: Yup, it looks like there's a problem with resolving that symlink. Don't know if it's a bug in SF/Assetic or a problem with your setup. Which SF version are you using?

Comment: Ok, thx. I'll check that. Nice idea. I had problems with all Symfony Versions since 2.3. I also tried 2.5 and updated yesterday to 2.7 to check if the "bug" is gone. Thanks in advance, I try to find the broken symlink in the filesystem.

Comment: It turns out that the Bundle called BraincraftedBootstrapBundle was buggy and mishandle the path to assets. After removing it to add Twitter Bootstrap manually, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, there seems to be a problem with the symlink from `web` to `htdocs`. Don't know if it's a bug in Symfony/Assetic or your local installation.

However, you don't even need that symlink. If you need the document root to be named `htdocs`, you can tell Symfony to use that directory:

In the application's `composer.json`, there should be an entry `"symfony-web-dir": "web"`. Change the value to `htdocs`, and you should be fine. You should also remove the symlink from `web` to `htdocs`, to avoid confusion.

I haven't tested this, but I'd expect all Symfony distribution packages, including Assetic, to respect this setting. If Assetic doesn't, simply call Assetic with `htdocs` as target parameter.

And, you should remove the `read_from` and `write_to` parameters from your configuration. Your values are the default anyway, so there's no need to hardcode them.

Hope this helps.