# Symfony2 assetic:dump replaced urls in javascript files. How to avoid this?

Tags: php, symfony, assetic

I'm using next command to generate static javascript/css files for production server in Symfony2:

```
app/console assetic:dump
```

Also in config I have next:

```
assetic:
    debug: "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
```

But I found that Assetic in Symfony also replace urls in javascript files. It is fine, but for some js libraries it it problem. For example for jsTree jQuery plugin. Here is place in [code](https://github.com/vakata/jstree/blob/master/dist/jstree.js#L2422) that Symfony understand incorrectly and I have in result something like:

```
node.childNodes[1].childNodes[0].style.backgroundImage = 'url('../bundles/bundlename/js/plugins/jsTree/+obj.icon+')';
```

I research Assetic configs on Symfony pages and even removed rules for css "cssrewrite: ~" from configs :) But no effect for js code. Probably someone know how I can deprecate to Assetic replace urls for javascript via config.yml? Or is there other solutions for current situation?

As variant for me - just modify this place in jsTree library to do not have problem with Symfony. But it is not good solution as for me...

Comment: Check this, possible duplicated.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30583095/symfony2-asseticdump-wrong-write-to-path